# Computation of ROC curve data points (Receiver operator characteristic)

Tags: statistics, set, roc

Given a particular threshhold e, I am able to generate two sets of the following format :-

```
Set<String> observedDocs;
Set<String> actualDocs;
```

Now I have to come up with True Positive Rate and False Positive Rates. The TPR is easy to calculate, its a really intuitive definition of recall which I do in the following manner:-

```
private double recall(final Set<String> observedDocs, final Set<String> actualDocs) {
    Set<String> relevantAndRetrieved = new HashSet<>(observedDocs);
    relevantAndRetrieved.addAll(actualDocs);
    return relevantAndRetrieved.size() / actualLabels.size();
}
```

I need some equivalent set manipulation based way to compute the False Positive rate. I dont want to compute the False positive, False Negative  counts etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the FPR is proportion of negative examples which are marked positive by the classifier. But I don't see how to express that in terms of the variables you have. How is your `recall` function working anyway? `observedLabels` and `actualLabels` are going to have at most 2 elements, right? Did you mean to make those `List` instead of `Set` ??

Comment: apologies, i meant observedDocs and actualDocs. I edited the code to reflect that.